# JSQMessagesViewController Click on message action

Tags: ios, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I have implemented JSQMessagesViewController into my app, and it has been excellent thus far.

However, I wish to allow a user to click on certain image messages in the list that would then take them to to another view controller.

Is this possible with JSQMessagesViewController?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, there is a delegate methods of JSQMessagesCollectionView

```
func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView, didTapMessageBubbleAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
}
```

from there you can get the data of selected bubble and as per the data you can redirect the user to the next controller.

Comment: In Swift? (The tag notes `Swift`)

Comment: Yes, in swift also you can do that.

Comment: No your answer should be in `Swift`, given the tag indicates `Swift`

Comment: Updated the answer to swift.